# Test of a regex (substring) occurs anywhere in any of the items in an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

My spec wants to test if a certain substring occurs withing any entry of an array of strings.

```
p @banner.errors.messages[:base] #=> ["Specify a leader text or an image, not both"]
```

All my spec really wants to know, is whether or not the "not both" string occurs in any of the array-items in there.

```
 @banner.errors.messages[:base].should include(/not both/)
```

fails, because `"not both"` is not included in `["Specify a leader text or an image, not both"]`

Note: When I test against the literal string (should include("Specify...both"), things work. But that seems dirty to me. Such user-faced texts are not critical for the test to pass; and such texts will change: every time the error message is changed, I will need to update my tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
@banner.errors.messages[:base].join.should match(/not both/)
```

But note that there is a edge case where the match might be over two or more lines, e.g. a line ending with "not " and the next line is " both".

Comment: That caused a D'OH moment over here. Stupid that I did not come up with that myself :). Thanks!

Comment: Also: the test should be "match(/not both/)" in your case.

Comment: Ah ok, have updated my answer. I haven't really used rspec myself that much.